# Construct query based on conditions using knex.js and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, knex.js

I want to construct a query, that depending if *name* and/or *city* were passed, it should add a *where* clause.

I don't find a specific way for doing that in the documentation, so I tried to append the *where* methods in the query, but probably failed to specify the types.

```
let query: Knex.QueryBuilder = await knex<Member>('members')

if (name) {
  query = query.where('name', String(name))
}

if (city) {
  query = query.where('city', String(city))
}

const members: Member[] = query.select('*')
```

`TypeError: query.select is not a function`

Also, TypeScript warnings:

*let query*

`Type 'Member[]' is missing the following properties from type 'QueryBuilder<any, any>': client, or, not, and, and 118 more.`

*const members*

`Type 'QueryBuilder<any, DeferredKeySelection<any, string, false, {}, false, {}, never> | DeferredKeySelection<any, string, false, {}, false, {}, never>[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Member[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Knex.js has a fake `then` implementation which upon call will execute the query on the DB.

Therefore you just need to move the `await` (which calls then) into the last part.

It should look like this:

```js
let query: Knex.QueryBuilder = knex<Member>('members');
// ---------------------------^

if (name) {
  query = query.where('name', String(name));
}

if (city) {
  query = query.where('city', String(city));
}

const members: Member[] = await query.select('*');
```

A better looking construction will be using [`modify`](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#modify).

```js
const members: Member[] = await knex<Member>('members')
  .select('*')
  .modify((queryBuilder) => {
    if (name) {
      queryBuilder.where('name', String(name));
    }

    if (city) {
      queryBuilder.where('city', String(city));
    }

    return queryBuilder;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```js
const query = knex.select('*')
.from('members as mb')

if (name) {
  query = query.where('name', String(name));
}

if (city) {
  query = query.whereRaw(`( mb.city = 'A' OR mb.city = 'P' )`);
}

const result = await query;
```

using these (package.json):

```json
 "knex": "^2.4.2",
 "mysql": "^2.18.1"
```